# How does Google sets HTTP Referrer after a search result click

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, google-search, referrer-policy

For example, the first search result on [this page](https://www.google.ru/search?hl=en&q=How%20does%20Google%20set%20the%20HTTP%20Referrer&gws_rd=cr&ei=G1RpVpalMuO6ygPOqr-YBg) leads to the older SO question, with the following HTTP request:

```
GET /questions/4402502/how-does-google-set-the-http-referrer-when-someone-clicks-on-a-search-result-lin HTTP/1.1
Host    stackoverflow.com
Referer https://www.google.ru
```

Note, that:

1. Only the domain is included in the Referer header, no query string.
2. Google is open via HTTPS, while SO is open via plain HTTP - nevertherless, the Referer header is sent by the browser.
3. There are no server-side redirects involved, the first HTTP query to open after the click is to the target site.

The question is, how do they achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google makes use of [Referrer Policy](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/referrer-policy/).
They include the meta tag in the page:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

This tells browsers to use "Origin Only" policy, that is, to send domain only information in the Referrer header in any subsequent request.