# How redirect the specific page to another page if the referer is from google search

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-referer

I searched a lot on different topics but this problem has not asked yet.

I want to redirect http://examplesite.com/page1 to http://examplesite.com/page2 using .htacess file, if and only if the user is coming to this page from google search engine.

in other words, the user should not be redirected in the below conditions:

1. if the user is not visiting the page1
2. if the user is visiting the page1 but http_refere is not equal to google

Comment: This might be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200125/how-does-google-sets-http-referrer-after-a-search-result-click

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect using htaccess based on referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106299/redirect-using-htaccess-based-on-referrer)

Comment: Also, regarding your first point, how on earth would someone NOT visiting page1 be redirected from page1 to page2? Mystical forces?

Comment: Google’s response headers include `Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`, so unless your page is using HTTPS, you should not be getting any referrer to begin with.